# Number of transactions in block

Tags: transactions, block

why sometimes block has 16 transactions and sometimes over 2000?
I checked it on https://blockexplorer.com/blocks.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the block size is fixed (but has changed since genesis block) there are 2 main reasons:

1. Transactions are not all the same size in bytes. One transaction can have multiple inputs and outputs, increasing the size of the tx in bytes.
2. The market might not fill a block with transactions (esp. in the beginning blocks) because usage is low.